# Clearing a question's migration history doesn't restore its deleted answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration, moderator-tools, deleted-answers

We're cleaning up questions that were wrongfully migrated to Programmers by the community *-cough subjective anecdotes polls find me a job cough-* To do this on our end, I first clear an original question's migration history, then close it again as not constructive.

On doing this today, I discovered that answers to the question that were posted on the original site weren't automatically restored when I cleared the migration data.

Here's the question I performed it on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358572/first-programming-language-to-learn (and its [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8358572/revisions))

I'm pretty sure I used the "clear migration history" option to undo the migration before closing the question again. Did something go wrong in the backend?

Comment: No, something didn't go wrong; that's how it was designed. But I agree that it is a bit odd. Note that "Clear Migration History" does just that; it removes the migration history and URL redirect from the *question.* It doesn't undelete the answers (answer deletion being a side-effect of the question migration); you currently have to do that separately.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I could have sworn that it undeleted the answers.

Comment: I'm almost certain that it did at one time. Presumably, reversible migrations happen fairly early in the life cycle of a question (when there are few answers), when answer undeletion is still a minor housekeeping detail.  Migration reversals require coordination on both sites anyway, so it's not like you can make them completely turnkey.

Comment: But if it is a bug or reversion, it would be nice to get it fixed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting with the next build, clearing a migration history will:

1. restore reputation to where it should be within 5 minutes
2. undelete answers that were deleted as part of the migration itself